# Java Hibernate Envers UpdateLockingStrategy warning HHH000416 On AuditTable

Tags: java, hibernate, locking, hibernate-envers, audit-tables

Hi we have a server running with Hibernate the classes are audited with envers.
Like this :

```
package db.shared;

import interfaces.GuiEditableTable;
import interfaces.ListableEntity;
import interfaces.ShortDescriptable;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditTable;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import common.Identifiable;
import common.Preferences;
import common.entity.EntityConcurrency;

@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Audited
@AuditTable(schema=Preferences.SCHEMA_AUDIT, value=Lizenz.CLASS_NAME+Preferences.AUDIT_SUFFIX)
@Table(schema = Preferences.SCHEMA_SHARED, uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { Lizenz.PROPERTY_LIZENZ_NAME }), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { Lizenz.PROPERTY_LIZENZ_NUMBER }) })
public class Lizenz extends common.entity.AbstractEntity
implements EntityConcurrency, ListableEntity, ShortDescriptable, GuiEditableTable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 589201271279697573L;
public static final String CLASS_NAME = "Lizenz";
public static final String PROPERTY_LIZENZ_NAME = "lizenzName";
public static final String PROPERTY_LIZENZ_NUMBER = "lizenzNummer";
public static final String MTM_PROPERTY_NAME = "lizenz";

public static final int LIZENZ_NUMBER_PADDING = 4;



@Id
@Column(name = Identifiable.PROPERTY_ID, columnDefinition = Preferences.DDL_TYPE_ID)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long ID;

@Version @Column(name = EntityConcurrency.PROPERTY_VERSION)
private long version;


private String lizenzName;
private String logo;

.
.
.
}
```

At the serverstart there warnings like that:

```
15:14:49 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.lock.UpdateLockingStrategy] HHH000416: Write locks via update not supported for non-versioned entities [db.shared.Lizenz_AUD]
15:14:49 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.lock.UpdateLockingStrategy] HHH000416: Write locks via update not supported for non-versioned entities [db.shared.Lizenz_AUD]
15:14:49 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.lock.UpdateLockingStrategy] HHH000416: Write locks via update not supported for non-versioned entities [db.shared.Lizenz_AUD]
15:14:49 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.lock.PessimisticReadUpdateLockingStrategy] HHH000416: Write locks via update not supported for non-versioned entities [db.shared.Lizenz_AUD]
15:14:49 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.lock.PessimisticWriteUpdateLockingStrategy] HHH000416: Write locks via update not supported for non-versioned entities [db.shared.Lizenz_AUD]
```

The Problem is that we are only have created the DB-Table for the Audit, we haven't any Audit-Classes. The Classes will be generated at startup, and we haven't found any @audit-Options to suppress these warnings. The Warnings are irrelevant for us because only write an Audit-entry once and never update it, and 5 warnings per class are flooding our log.

We are using hibernate-envers-4.1.10.Final.jar and hibernate-core-4.1.10.Final.jar with java 1.7.

Does anyone have the same problem or know howto fix it.
we are grateful for any Help.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in source code of hibernate :

```
public UpdateLockingStrategy(Lockable lockable, LockMode lockMode) {

    this.lockable = lockable;

    this.lockMode = lockMode;

    if (lockMode.lessThan(LockMode.UPGRADE)) {

        throw new HibernateException("[" + lockMode + "] not valid for update statement");

    }

    if (!lockable.isVersioned()) {

        log.warn("write locks via update not supported for non-versioned entities [" + lockable.getEntityName() + "]");

        this.sql = null;

    } else {
        this.sql = generateLockString();

    }
}
```

and the document of isVersioned() :

```
/**
 * Determine whether optimistic locking by column is enabled for this
 * entity.
 *
 * @return True if optimistic locking by column (i.e., <version/> or
 * <timestamp/>) is enabled; false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isVersioned();
```

The consequence is if you want to use audit entity and don't give this warning , **you should enable optimistic locking by @Version on a column of your entity** :)

Comment: The Problem is how to do that, because we dont have an Audit-Object only the Table. The Object is generated by Hibernate.Envers at startup.